# How do I redirect a 404 while maintaining the 404 status?

Tags: asp.net, html, iis, iis-manager

Using iis Manager, I set 404's to `execute a URL on this site`. However, checking with Google Webmaster tools' "Fetch as Google" I see that the response has a code 200.

How do I fix this?

Comment: I have tested it and it does return a code 200 (same result when using the `customErrors`). What you could do is set up yourself the header on the page where you are redirected but I am not sure this is a proper way to do...

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Now I know it's not just a bug on my site.